# Setting Title for Row in PickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipickerview

I am struggling trying to set my titleForRow in my PickerView. Currently, I have a picker that accesses a user's playlist data. Then I want to transfer it to the picker. However, I know the picker data is correct because of the didSelectRow method. I have been unlucky in trying to display the actual data in the PickerView.

**I have edited my code to what I have now. Currently, Purchased is repeated over and over inside my pickerview. Is there a way to fix it?

```
   -(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [_roundArray count];
    return [_timeArray count];

    MPMediaQuery *myPlaylistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
    NSArray *playlists = [myPlaylistsQuery collections];

    return [playlists count];

}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView.tag == 1) {
        lblRound.text = [_roundArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else if (pickerView.tag == 2) {
        lblTime.text = [_timeArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else if (pickerView.tag ==3) {

        MPMediaQuery *myPlaylistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
        NSArray *playlists = [myPlaylistsQuery collections];

        for (MPMediaPlaylist *playlist in playlists) {
            lblPlaylist.text = [playlist valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName];
    }
}

}

#pragma mark Picker Delegate Methods

- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSString *title;

    if (pickerView.tag == 1) // this is otherPickerview
    {
        title=[_roundArray objectAtIndex:row]; // your logic to get title for otherpickerview

    }
    else if (pickerView.tag == 2) // this is citysPickerview
    {
        title=[_timeArray objectAtIndex:row]; // your logic to get title for cityspickerview

    }
    else if (pickerView.tag == 3)
    {
        [self showPlaylistData];

        MPMediaQuery *myPlaylistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
        NSArray *playlists = [myPlaylistsQuery collections];

        for (MPMediaPlaylist *playlist in playlists)
            title = [playlist valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName];
    }

    return title;

}
```

Comment: So what's your actual problem? Wrong data displaying? No data displaying? Runtime error? FWIW, assumptions about data in one method don't necessarily apply to separate methods.

Comment: No data is displaying.

Comment: If no data is displaying, your root cause could be (aside from a poor design -- you should really look at Matt's answer about datasources): (1) titleForRow: not getting called, (2) pickerView.tag not equal to 1, 2, or 3 (note you have no catchall fallback case for when this is the case), (3) the array in question is nil, or (4) the objectAtIndex: for the array in question is an empty string. Set a breakpoint on your first if statement and step through it, checking the value of each of the variables each time you move forward.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have failed to set this class up as your picker view's data source, and you have failed to implement the data source methods. Thus, no data. Consult the [documentation on UIPickerViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIPickerViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html). (Or just look at any working example and base your code on that.)

Comment: Specifically, implement these two methods from `UIPickerViewDataSource` `- numberOfComponentsInPickerView:` and `
- pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:`. If you want to quickly test it, just return 1 for both.

Comment: There is data there. I can see what data is there by using the lblPlaylist.text. However the data is blank in the picker. Therefore, I am able to select the different playlists. I am unsure of what you mean by setting up my data source. The data source is connected to the playlist Picker.

Comment: Prove that `_array1` is not `nil`, please.

Comment: Also your code makes no sense. You seem to be coding for three different picker views at once. Delete all the code except the code for _just one_ picker view.